# JSOM/SP.js from Angular?

Tags: sharepoint

We have some SharePoint (SP 2013 and SP Online) applications developed in Angular which are uploaded to a document library and access SP data via SP's web services (REST).  Is there a way 
to utilize JSOM from such an application (i.e. not a 'SharePoint Addin' or SPFX)?  I've been looking at SharePointPlus and it's pretty nice and I got it working from Angular pretty easily but there's so much existing material (discussions, examples, etc) on SP.js that it would be nice to use it directly if it was straight forward to do.

Answer (score 0):

They are client side APIs, you could use either of them.

Sample demo([Or REST api demo from here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d7c690f3-0036-401d-9f8e-cfdcd2edb1d2/how-to-refresh-or-reload-the-controller-in-angularjs-after-adding-the-list-items?forum=sharepointdevelopment)):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sharepointplus/browser/sharepointplus.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var spApp = angular
            .module("spApp", [])
            .controller("viewItemsController", function ($scope) {
                $SP().list('Contacts').get({
                    fields: "Title,sNumber,Name,Amount,ID"
                })
                .then(function (data) {
                    var jsonResult = [];
                    for (var i = data.length; i--;) {
                        jsonResult.push({ ID: data[i].getAttribute("ID"), Title: data[i].getAttribute("Title"), sNumber: data[i].getAttribute("sNumber"), Name: data[i].getAttribute("Name"), Amount: data[i].getAttribute("Amount") });
                    }                    
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.contacts = jsonResult;
                    });
                });
            })
    </script>
    <h3>View Contacts</h3>
    <hr />
    <div ng-app="spApp">
        <div ng-controller="viewItemsController">
            <div ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
                {{contact.ID}}: {{contact.Title}}, {{contact.sNumber}}, {{contact.Name}}, {{contact.Amount}}
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  As mentioned, I already have SharePointPlus working from Angular.  Do you have an example of using SP.js from Angular 2+ ?